# PlayStation 4 dlc different region

Tags: psn, ps4, region-lock, playstation-plus

Hi I've encountered a problem. I bought my ps4 in NA. It came with free download from the PSN store. I brought it to Singapore with me. I signed up a Asia pan account. I can't download the games anymore. I asked the people from PlayStation they said I needed to be in USA to download the content. Is there a way around this? Do I have to get a VPN? Or can I just register and say I'm from NA?

Comment: the latter, create a PSN account with a US Address. make sure when you buy games that could have DLC you know which region they are for as while games are Region Free DLC must match to the region of the game. don't know anything about VPNs so no idea if it's a better option

Comment: I have Japanese titles on my NA PS4 by using a Japanese account. I'm certain that if the download it region-locked, it would be by account.

Comment: All downloads are account-region-bound. Just create or use an US-PSN Account and you will be fine.